# How to highlight the border of bar on clicking it using chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have the following code, where a bar chart is constructed using chart js. When I click on a bar, I am able to highlight the clicked bar alone in yellow color. But when I click the next bar, that also gets highlighted and the previous bar also is highlighted. How to modify the code such that only one bar is highlighted when I click and remains that way, until I click the next bar.

```
var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("trendChart"), {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["Pink", "Purple", "Blue", "Yellow", "Black", "Green"],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          backgroundColor: ['RGB(170,37,120,0.5)','RGB(111,44,121,0.5)','RGB(60,48,120,0.5)','RGB(60,48,120,0.5)','RGB(49,64,134,0.5)','RGB(6,87,106,0.5)'],
          borderWidth: 2,
        }]      
      },
      options:{
      
        onClick: event => {
           
            var element = myChart.getElementAtEvent(event);
            if(element.length >= 0){
                element[0]._chart.controller.config.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[element[0]._index]._model.borderColor = "rgb(255,255,0)";
                myChart.render(0,true);}
          },
               scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                fontColor:'#fff'
               }
            }],
                        xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                fontColor:'#fff'
              }
             }],                    
         },
       legend:{
          display:false
        }
      }
    })
```